# Problems implementing ordering and paging in NHibernate's QueryOver API for queries using joins and projections

Tags: c#, nhibernate, queryover

I'm still trying to get the hang of NHibernate. I'm doing some queries with projections, and so far I managed to come up with this:

```
var restrictions = Restrictions.Conjunction();
// add some restrictions

var qo = Session.QueryOver(() => tenantAlias)
    .JoinAlias(x => x.Customer, () => customerAlias)
    .Where(restrictions)                
    .SelectList(list => list
        .Select(() => tenantAlias.Id).WithAlias(() => item.TenantId)
        .Select(() => tenantAlias.DomainName.Value).WithAlias(() => item.DomainName)
        .Select(() => customerAlias.Code.Value).WithAlias(() => item.CustomerCode)
        .Select(() => customerAlias.DisplayName).WithAlias(() => item.CustomerName)
        .Select(() => tenantAlias.ActivationPeriod.From).WithAlias(() => item.ActivationPeriodFrom)
        .Select(() => tenantAlias.ActivationPeriod.Until).WithAlias(() => item.ActivationPeriodUntil)
        .Select(() => tenantAlias.PurchasedLicenses.Value).WithAlias(() => item.PurchasedLicenses)
    )
    .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<TenantQueryResult.Item>());

    var items = await qo.ListAsync<TenantQueryResult.Item>();
```

Following a DDD approach, Tenant is an aggregate root and Customer an entity, and they have a one-to-one relationship. So far, this query is working beautifully.

Now, however, I would like to order the result set by customer's displayname property. I found there's an OrderBy method, so I thought it simple enough to add the following line:

```
.OrderBy(() => customerAlias.DisplayName)
```

But alas, this doesn't compile. The reason is that the query over always returns an instance of `IQueryOver<T, T>`, but the OrderBy clause returns `IQueryOver<T>` only. And `IQueryOver<T>` does not have a `SelectList` or `TransformUsing` or even `ListAsync` method. So I don't get how `OrderBy` clauses should work. The NHibernate documentation [1] doesn't provide an example, and Googling only got me simple examples with Cats, but never with joins or transforms or projections.

The same thing happens when I try to add paging to my query. Both Take and Skip methods are available, but they have the same problem, both return `IQueryOver<T>` instead of `IQueryOver<T, T>`.

The question is, then, how I'm supposed to add ordering and paging clauses with QueryOver API, when using joins and projections? Thanks in advance.

[1] http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/queryqueryover.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to add direction ASC or DESC. So instead of this

```
.OrderBy(() => customerAlias.DisplayName)
.TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<TenantQueryResult.Item>());
```

We have to add `.Asc` or `.Desc`

```
.OrderBy(() => customerAlias.DisplayName)
    .Asc
.TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<TenantQueryResult.Item>());
```